# Tkinter Calculator Bug

Tags: python, math, tkinter, calculator

I am making a simple Python Tk calculator, but there is a bug: the calculator won't work unless I push one of the buttons before then numbers are put in when I do this it diplays an error that says "Enter Numeric Values!" after it does that then it will calculate the input numbers but if I just open it and input numbers it won't work

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import math

def calculate():
    try:
        num1 = float(enter1.get())
        num2 = float(enter2.get())
        result = num1 * num2
        label3.config(text=str(result))
    except ValueError:
        label3.config(text='Enter numeric values!', fg="white")

def calculate2():
    try:
        num1 = float(enter1.get())
        num2 = float(enter2.get())
        result = num1 / num2
        label3.config(text=str(result))
    except ValueError:
        label3.config(text='Enter numeric values!', fg="white")

def calculate3():
    try:
        num1 = float(enter1.get())
        num2 = float(enter2.get())
        result = num1 + num2
        label3.config(text=str(result))
   except ValueError:
        label3.config(text='Enter numeric values!',fg="white")

def calculate4():
    try:
        num1 = float(enter1.get())
        num2 = float(enter2.get())
        result = num1 - num2
        label3.config(text=str(result))
    except ValueError:
        label3.config(text='Enter numeric values!',fg="white")

def calculate5():
    try:
        num1 = float(enter1.get())
        result = num1**2
        label3.config(text=str(result))
    except ValueError:
        label3.config(text='Enter numeric values!',fg="white")

def calculate6():
    try:
        num1 = float(enter1.get())
        result = math.sqrt(num1)
        label3.config(text=str(result))
    except ValueError:
        label3.config(text='Enter numeric values!',fg="white")


root = Tk()
root.configure(background='black')
root.wm_title("Calc")

label1 = Label(root, text='First Number:',bg="black", fg="white")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan=2)
enter1 = Entry(root, bg='white')
enter1.grid(row=1, column=0,columnspan=2)

label2 = Label(root, text='Second Number:',bg="black", fg="white")
label2.grid(row=2, column=0,columnspan=2)
enter2 = Entry(root, bg='white')
enter2.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

btn1 = Button(root, text='-Multiply-', command=calculate,                                       bg="  black",activebackground="green", fg="white")
btn1.grid(row=4, column=0)
btn2 = Button(root, text='-Divide-', command=calculate2,  bg="black",activebackground="orange", fg="white")
btn2.grid(row=5, column=0)
btn3 = Button(root, text='-Add-', command=calculate3, bg="black",activebackground="purple", fg="white")
btn3.grid(row=5, column=1)
btn4 = Button(root, text='-Subtract-', command=calculate4, bg="black",activebackground="red", fg="white")
btn4.grid(row=4, column=1)
btn5 = Button(root, text='Square (Only First #)', command=calculate5, bg="black",activebackground="cyan", fg="white")
btn5.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2)
btn6 = Button(root, text='Square Root (only First #)', command=calculate6, bg="black",activebackground="yellow", fg="white")
btn6.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=2,)
label3 = Label(root, bg="black")
label3.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=2)

enter1.focus()
enter1.bind('<Return>', func=lambda e:enter2.focus_set())
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works without any problem, the only issue is that the text color is initially black. That is why it "works" before displaying an error, because that option sets the `fg` option to white, and in the next changes it keeps the same text color that has been configured.

To solve this, just set the `fg` option to `"white"` when you create the Label widget:

```
label3 = Label(root, bg="black", fg="white")
```

Comment: Than you! i guess i just didnt catch that